# Why web application running on phusion passenger is getting down frequently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

My web application running on phusion passenger is getting down frequently but i am not able to trace out the reason.
Here is the error i got in /var/log/httpd/error.log file

Premature end of script headers: 
The backend application (process 5417) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.

Last 50 line of log:

```
[Thu Oct 11 05:29:42 2012] [error] [client 11.992.88.255] Premature end of script headers: 
[ pid=22252 thr=1 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:817 time=2012-10-11 05:29:42.409 ]: The backend application (process 5488) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:16 2012] [notice] child pid 27200 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:19 2012] [notice] child pid 27196 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:19 2012] [notice] child pid 27199 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:20 2012] [notice] child pid 27203 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:20 2012] [notice] child pid 27195 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:20 2012] [notice] child pid 27205 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:28 2012] [notice] child pid 27194 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:28 2012] [notice] child pid 27206 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:35 2012] [notice] child pid 27193 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:38 2012] [notice] child pid 27204 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:38 2012] [notice] child pid 27192 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:40 2012] [notice] child pid 27202 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:42 2012] [notice] child pid 27197 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:35:43 2012] [notice] child pid 27198 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:37:31 2012] [notice] child pid 27207 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:02 2012] [notice] child pid 9225 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:02 2012] [notice] child pid 9224 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:03 2012] [notice] child pid 9229 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:04 2012] [notice] child pid 9230 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:05 2012] [notice] child pid 9231 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:06 2012] [notice] child pid 9392 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:07 2012] [notice] child pid 9395 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:08 2012] [notice] child pid 9396 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:39:09 2012] [notice] child pid 27201 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:41:55 2012] [notice] child pid 9220 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:45:25 2012] [notice] child pid 9223 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:52:40 2012] [notice] child pid 9517 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:54:16 2012] [notice] child pid 9525 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:54:17 2012] [notice] child pid 9529 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:54:18 2012] [notice] child pid 9531 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Oct 11 05:54:19 2012] [notice] child pid 10414 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
/home/john/dips/apps/production/releases/20121005650832/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `initialize' may cause serious problems
/home/john/dips/apps/production/releases/20121005650832/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
/home/john/apps/production/releases/20121005650832/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `__send__' may cause serious problems
[DEPRECATED] By requiring 'spreadsheet/excel' you are loading a Compatibility
             layer which provides a drop-in replacement for Spreadsheet::Excel
             versions <= 0.3.5.1. This code will be removed in Spreadsheet
             version 1.0.0

/home/john/dips/apps/production/releases/20121005650832/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `initialize' may cause serious problems
/home/john/dips/apps/production/releases/20121005650832/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
/home/john/dips/apps/production/releases/20121005650832/vendor/gems/ruby/1.9/gems/needle-1.3.0/lib/needle/definition-context.rb:36: warning: undefining `__send__' may cause serious problems
[DEPRECATED] By requiring 'spreadsheet/excel' you are loading a Compatibility
             layer which provides a drop-in replacement for Spreadsheet::Excel
             versions <= 0.3.5.1. This code will be removed in Spreadsheet
             version 1.0.0

    enter code here
```

Comment: can i get the last 50 lines of production.log?

Comment: @beck03076 Thanks.I have added last 50 lines of log. please check.

Comment: Can you figure it out on your own now?

Comment: I tried but didn't get the solution. i changed phusion passenger's configuration but still it is getting down.

Comment: In your Gemfile change this gem "spreadsheet-excel" ' to this 'gem "spreadsheet-excel", "~> 0.3.5.1" '

Comment: join this chat room..http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue of gem spreadsheet-excel version.

Comment: somewhere in your controller you must have this line "require "spreadsheet/Excel" "... change that to require 'spreadsheet'